# Running a program on riscv/Linux (spike)

Tags: linux, riscv

I'm running Linux on spike as described at: http://riscv.org/download.html#tab_linux. With busybox I have a powerful tool to run several usefull tools. The next thing I am trying to achieve, is to run my own program on riscv/Linux. Therefore I wrote a little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  printf("Hello world!\n"); 

return 0; }
```

compiled it with riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc and added the binary to the root.img of riscv/Linux. The Problem I now have is, that if I want to execute the program under riscv/Linux threw ./hello, the following message appears on my shell:

```
-/bin/ash: ./hello: not found
```

My Question now is (1) what am I doing wrong and (2) is there at all a possibility to run a program on riscv/Linux the way I am trying accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your hello program is dynamically linked to a runtime library that is missing from your root file system.

You can use 'ldd' to find which dynamic libraries your application is linked with and make sure all of them are present on the root file system or simply compile the hello program statically.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. The runtime libraries are provided in ($TOP)/riscv/sysroot/lib.

Comment: @Chris I'm glad that my advice was helpful. How about marking the answer correct?